# Create file with logger

Tags: java, java-8

I am creating a .log file in a specific path, but I have a problem, create a static class and every time I call the method of writingLike a new .log file is created, it is necessary that the registry always remain on the same file.

Here is the test code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class Utils {

    public static void escribirLog(String rutaArchivo, String mensaje) {

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
        FileHandler fh;

        try {

            fh = new FileHandler(rutaArchivo);
            logger.addHandler(fh);

            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);

            logger.info(mensaje);

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
            escribirLog("C:\\rutaLog\\archivo.log", "MensajePrueba"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

What can I do to always write the log on the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a FileHandler with the append option enabled to append to an existing log file.

On the line where you construct your fileHandler, change it from

```
    new FileHandler(fileName)
```

to

```
    new FileHandler(fileName, true)
```

This makes use of [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) which tells FileHandler to append to the file.

Comment: Thanks @konsolas, Already add the line `new FileHandler(fileName, true)`.
However, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Additional to this it is necesary to closed the FileHandler at the end with `fh.close();` so that it write in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `FileHandler` and adding it to the logger instance every time you call that method. You end up with multiple handlers trying to write to the same filename at the same time, the first one creates the file and locks it so the rest have to use alternate filenames.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Try to create the file before generating the log, but the same thing is still happening.

Comment: You probably need to enable appending, too (see the other answer).